# How to make a radiobutton text bold?

Tags: asp.net

I have a radiobutton and want to show its text as bold.

1) I have tried with

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonLevel0" runat="server" 
                 GroupName="ItemAccess" value="0" AutoPostBack="true" 
                 oncheckchanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" 
                 Text="Only to Me" Font-Bold="true"/>
```

... But it is still showing the text with normal font-weight.

---

2) I have tried with

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonLevel0" runat="server"
                 GroupName="ItemAccess" value="0" AutoPostBack="true" 
                 oncheckchanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>
  <b>Only To Me</b>
</asp:RadioButton>`
```

But this is producing an error.

Comment: You're going to need to provide actual, valid code in order for this to be tracked down. What you've provided will result in a parser error, but a simple `<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbBold" Text="Text here" Font-Bold="true"></asp:RadioButton>` produces bold text on my screen.

Comment: You must have some css being applied to the radiobutton that overrides the bold setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is surely because of css of parent control. check with inspect element and know which parent control is cause for this. For example if `label` is the cause then modify the css class as

```css
.bold > label {
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

... This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

## Try out the below code snippet:

```
<asp:radiobutton ID="rdbText" runat="server" CssClass="bold" Text="Text"></asp:radiobutton>
<style type="text/css">
.bold
{
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Comment: @wilson lookout here If you have some css property already applied so now use
`.bold
{
    font-weight:bold !important;
}`

Comment: @Wilson- Does this answer your query?

Comment: Not Exactly. but your answer is rit. i think i have some other issue with parent css.

Answer (score 2):

Its surly because of CSS..you can also check it..install the firebug or use any developer tool to inspect the element..it will show you which css is overriding it..
I think this can slow your problem..try this.

define a css on your page in which your radio button is than apply this css on your radio button..

```
<style type="text/css">
.bold
{
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
</style>
```

"!important" will override every thing..

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" runat ="server" Text ="check1" style="font-weight :bold;"   />
```

Comment: so what is the difference between font-bold="true" and style="font-weight:bold"?

Comment: are you using any controls with css

Answer (score 0):

use style=>font-weight for making radio button bold:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" style="font-weight: 900" Text="test" />
```

if it doesn't  work, it is because of parent CSS. if you have chrome you can use developer tools to see where exactly the Inherited CSS comes from. if you have IE you can use F12 for developer tools. Trace Syle it show you the reason

Comment: so surly it is because of parent CSS. if you have chrome you can use developer tools to see where exactly the Inherited CSS comes from

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="RadioButton12" runat="server" Text="test1" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="RadioButton12" runat="server" Text="test2" />

<style>
input[type="radio"] + label {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: gray;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: initial;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

```css
input[type="radio"] + label {
  font-weight: normal !important;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: initial;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="mygroup" runat="server" Text="test1" /><br />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="mygroup" runat="server" Text="test2" />

<span><input id="MainContent_RadioButton1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButton12" value="RadioButton1" checked="checked"><label for="MainContent_RadioButton1">Test1</label></span><br>

<span><input id="MainContent_RadioButton2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButton12" value="RadioButton2"><label for="MainContent_RadioButton2">Test2</label></span>
```